# Python error when executing script

Tags: python, io

[image]I'm trying to control an I/O module using a python script. I'm seeing an error relating to a port not defined. Any ideas?

I've taken the code from the following link

https://github.com/jkesanen/usbrly08/blob/master/usbrly08.py

Thanks.

**Update**

Hi, thanks for the replies. I have tried to execute the script again with the port argument added. I now see a different error. My relay module is connected to com port 9. I have added the error I see after running the script above in the initial post. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\A1037648>cd \python

C:\Python>test.py -p9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Test.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python\Test.py", line 217, in main
    s = serial.Serial(args.port, timeout=args.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in 
__init__
    super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 240, in 
__init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in 
open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: 
{!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '9': WindowsError(2, 
'The system cannot find
the file specified.')

C:\Python>
```

Comment: You need to specify the port command line argument. `test.py -p 55000`

Comment: The message is clear run the script providing a port number with the flag -p

Comment: Terminal content is made of _text_. It should be shared _as text_, not as screenshots. Text can be copied and pasted into a text editor! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be efficiently searched! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be consumed by users of assistive technologies, like screenreaders! Screenshots cannot :-(. [Please give text the respect it deserves instead of banishing it to inaccessible image formats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).

Comment: Screenshots are ugly, especially with a small font. You can copy/paste the contents of a cmd-window as follows: click on the small icon in the top left corner, click 'Edit', click 'Select all', click icon again, click 'Edit', press <ENTER> (or click 'Copy'). The error message tells you that test.py requires an argument - see the `usage: ` part of the message.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I have tried to execute the script again with the port argument added. I now see a different error. My relay module is connected to com port 9. I have added the error I see after running the script above in the initial post. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Did you VERIFY the usb_rly08b board is fully recognized by Windows? Have you checked the driver installation through the test program provided on e.g. http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/usb_rly08btech.htm ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I have already downloaded that test application and i'm successfully connecting to the relay device

Answer (score 0):

Something like `test.py -p COM9` or `test.py -p COM9:` should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help with this one. I've just got back to trying it again and it works! I have attached the code I'm using to control the IO module if anyone finds it useful.

```
echo[

cd..

timeout /t 1

cd..

timeout /t 1

cd..

timeout /t 1

cd python27

timeout /t 1

test.py -p com6 -n 0
```